# How to edit duplicates in a List?

Tags: c#, list

I'm using a DropDownList with `cId` (course id) and `cName` (course name). However, if there's a duplicated `cName`, I would like to join `startDate` with the `cName`. Like:  `$"cName ({startDate})"`

This is how my list look like:

```
var list = new List<(int cId, string cName, string startDate)>
{
    (1, "Math", "1/12"),
    (2, "Music", "1/12"),
    (3, "English", "1/12"),
    (4, "English", "11/4"),
    (5, "Swedish", "1/12"),
    (6, "Russia", "1/12")
};
```

*Since there's two* `cName` *with English,* `startDate` *should be added into it's string, like*:

```
cId    cName
----   -----
 1   | "Math"
 2   | "Music"
 3   | "English (1/12)"
 4   | "English (11/4)"
 6   | "Swedish"
 7   | "Russia"
```

What I had in mind:

*if the list have any duplicated `cName`*, `cName = $"cName ({startDate})"`

**EDIT:**

This is how the list is added into the DropDownList:

```
foreach (var item in list)
      {
           dplCourse.Items.Add(new ListItem(item.cId, item.cName));
      }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to do a pass over the list to find which ones are duplicates and change the name of the duplicates before you add them to the display list.

```
var list = new List<(int cId, string cName, string startDate)>
{
    (1, "Math", "1/12"),
    (2, "Music", "1/12"),
    (3, "English", "1/12"),
    (4, "English", "11/4"),
    (5, "Swedish", "1/12"),
    (6, "Russia", "1/12")
};

var duplicates = new HashSet<string>(
            list.GroupBy(x => x.cName) //Group the items by name
                .Where(g => g.Count() > 1) //Find groups with more than 1
                .Select(g => g.Key)); //Just add the names to the HashSet, not the group

foreach (var item in list)
{
     var displayName = item.cName
     if(duplicates.Contains(displayName))
     {
         displayName += $" ({item.startDate})";
     }
     dplCourse.Items.Add(new ListItem(item.cId, displayName));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ to get the display names. You can group the items, check the number of items in the group and unroll the groups back into a flat list of items. Since you have an ID, you can order the items accordingly (the grouping messes up the order).

This all would look like this:

```
var listItemsQry =
    from item in list
    group item by item.cName into itemGrp
    let itemCount = itemGrp.Count()
    from groupedItem in itemGrp
    orderby groupedItem.cId
    let itemName = itemCount > 1 ?
        $"{groupedItem.cName} {groupedItem.startDate}" :
        groupedItem.cName
    select new ListItem(item.cId, itemName);

foreach(ListItem item in listItemsQry) {
    dplCourse.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: This will likely perform slightly faster than my solution because it does not create the extra hash set.

Comment: It might do so internally... @ScottChamberlain

Answer (score 0):

The most simplest and not so smart solution you can use is to make a list with those items, which are unique. You can achieve it as for example in that foreach use a condition if cName already exists in the temp list with unique values. After that to make a new second temp list with those items which has duplications and to put all of them as cName + startDate. Finally you can merge both temp list in a final one.